# Deploy SvelteKit with AWS Amplify

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

Hi I've been trying to deploy my Svelte kit 1.0 to AWS Amplify. I push the commits and then Amplify builds and verify the app pass , but then if I visit the app URL it's just a blank page. Please see build below.

```html
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /.svelte-kit/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: What adapter did you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish a SvelteKit app to AWS Amplify, you have to make sure to use the correct adapter which is `@sveltejs/adapter-static`. You also need to set the pretender default to true.

Reference [Deploy static Svelte-Kit app with AWS Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72816085/13631113)

Comment: Oh. Thankyou just change from auto to be static.

Comment: what if app is not static? like it has page.server.js and it fetches products from server? and also it submits forms to apis?

Comment: @FaisalShahzad, AWS Amplify is made for serving static content, there are other AWS software solutions out there that you can utilize if you need a server to serve your content